# Simple classlist.add("someclass") always giving an error

Tags: javascript, dom

This is a simple representation of what I'm facing

```js
var box=document.getElementsByClassName('foo')
    box.classList.add('things')
```

```css
    .foo{
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        background-color: aqua;
        border: 1px solid royalblue;
    }
    .things{
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="foo"></div>
</body>
```

Javascript console always returns these.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a list, so you need to specify the `index` as follows:

```
var box=document.getElementsByClassName('foo')[0];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a question though so what do i need to do to avoid referring to the index. Should I use element ID instead of class name? I did not check it but I just want to know.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes using an id returns one element only. It is better to do this if you are only changing the class of this element.